# Polytime Mapping Reduction from Language A to Language A (identity)

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, discrete-mathematics, polynomial-time-reductions

How would I create a polytime mapping reduction to prove A ≤p A for any language A.

I was thinking to assume A is in P to start.
For every : ∈ iff ()∈.

But I am not sure what to do from there, any advice? I don't get how to show that you can polytime reduce a function to itself, because if you assume A has a Turing machine and a polytime decider, a function that is a polytime mapper, then how do you show its equal to each other?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. What do you mean by "A **has** a Turing machine"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a polytime function $f$ with the following property:

> For every $x$: $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in A$.

You take it from here.